# compare the duplicate value of a column in one table to the value of another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables
first table is request table:-

```
user_id   name     requests
11        sharan    2
12        ram       3
11        dev       5
13        priya     4
12        nithin    6
```

second table is user type table:-

```
user_id    type
11         gold
12         silver
13         gold
14         platinum
15         gold
```

here in the request table the duplicate `user_id` is 11, I want a query to retrieve ths duplicate `user_id` from request table and compare that duplicate `user_id` to user type table to get the `user_type` of it.
here I want to get the duplicate `user_id` is 11 and its type is gold .

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you all `user_id`s that occur more than once in the `request` table:

```
select user_id
from request
group by user_id
having count(*) > 1
```

So we can use those results to show those users' types:

```
select user_id, type
from user_type
where user_id in 
  (select user_id
  from request
  group by user_id
  having count(*) > 1)
```

Produces:

```
| USER_ID |   TYPE |
|---------|--------|
|      11 |   gold |
|      12 | silver |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/718e5/3)